# Clear results when typeahead value is 0

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

When I delete the search text, it doesn't trigger a change.  I want to clear the results when someone deletes their query.

I'm using angular-ui bootstrap typeahead with `typeahead-min-length: 0`

Comment: Please share a piece of your code which reproduces the issue

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding I would suggest you to use the updated ui-Bootstrap code that supports `typeahead-min-length: 0`
. They have recently added the support for this feature. The angular-ui website still mentions that the minimum length should be 1. From the [website:](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

> typeahead-min-length $ (Default: 1) - Minimal no of characters that
>   needs to be entered before typeahead kicks-in. Must be greater than or
>   equal to 0.

Here is a working plunker from the  [pull request](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/4789).

http://plnkr.co/edit/JsEwGwoqckcnHMMOxVTN?p=preview